# Setting email alert between 108300 and 108500

Tags: python, email

I am fairly new to Python coding and need some help, I am trying to implement email sending when a scale gets to weights between 10839 and 10850

I know I can use `w>10840` and anything above this will trigger an email but the `hx711` connected to the pi occasionally spikes causing a false email to be sent so I need it to only send emails when the weight is between 10839 and 10850.

Here is a sample of the code I am using, note I used `==` but as the pi updates every 5 seconds I have found it can bypass the exact weight without setting off an email. That's why I want to set more of a range

```
if w==10840:
      if flag == 0:
        lcdclear()
        lcdprint("Fuel Cell Has Been Replenished")
        setCursor(0,1);
        lcdprint("Sending Email")
        server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.jon2.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login("jon2@jon2.com", "aaaa1111")
        msg = "Fuel Cell Has Been Replenished"
        server.sendmail("jon1@jon2.co.uk", msg)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: if 10839 < w <10850: ?

Answer (score 0):

To check if value is between a range you can use this:

```
if 10839 < w < 10850:
      if flag == 0:
        lcdclear()
        lcdprint("Fuel Cell Has Been Replenished")
        setCursor(0,1);
        lcdprint("Sending Email")
        server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.jon2.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login("jon2@jon2.com", "aaaa1111")
        msg = "Fuel Cell Has Been Replenished"
        server.sendmail("jon1@jon2.co.uk", msg)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh Much Appreciated, i will try this tomorrow